# Input/output stream?

Tags: c

Write a program that repeatedly (until end-of-file) reads in a character
from the input stream. If the character is upper case, change it to lower case
and write it to the output stream. For all other characters, write the
character unchanged to the output stream.
Use getchar() for input, Use putchar() for output, and use input redirection
for connecting the input file to the program (see page 16 of Quickstart).
C:>lowerCase < anyOldTextFile.txt
You will need an if-statement nested inside a while loop for this. It might
help to look at a table of ASCII.

I'm not asking for my homework to be done, I just really have no idea how to even start this and am just looking for some hints

Here's the code I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int c, l;
    printf("Enter Letter: ");
    scanf("%c ", &l);
    c=getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        if(l <= 'Z') {
            putchar(l);
        } else if (l <= 'z') {
            putchar(l);
        } else {
            c = EOF;
        }
        system("Pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: "You will need an if-statement nested inside a while loop for this." - he's probably right.

Comment: Read page 16 of "Quickstart"

Comment: Another hint: chars are really ints in C; you can test whether a char is upper- or lowercase by looking at it's int value (and to change it you do some math using the upper- and lowercase values which you can find in an ASCII-table, for example [here](http://www.asciitable.com)).

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 
 int c, l;
 printf("Enter Letter: "); 
 scanf("%c ", &l);

 c=getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
  {

  if(l <= 'Z')
  {
   putchar(l);
  }
  else if (l <= 'z')
  {
  putchar(l);
  }
  else
  {
   c = EOF;
  }
  
  
 system("Pause");
 }
  
}

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 
 int c, l;
 printf("Enter Letter: "); 
 scanf("%c ", &l);

 c=getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
  {

  if(l <= 'Z')
  {
   putchar(l);
  }
  else if (l <= 'z')
  {
  putchar(l);
  }
  else
  {
   c = EOF;
  }
  
  
 system("Pause");
 }
  
}

Comment: So they've told you that you need to read a file, use a loop, use specific functions.  You are presumably being taught the basic concepts of programming at the same time.  Will you please take the time to read up on file input/output and loops in C?  There is example code all over the web.  As a kid, I taught myself C before I'd even heard of the internet.  I read any code that I could find, and figured it out through trial and error.  Why does everyone want to shortcut a valid learning process these days?

Comment: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=read+char+from+file+until+EOF+c+&oq=read+char+from+file+until+EOF+c+&gs_l=hp.3...2203.16102.0.16541.32.25.0.6.6.0.92.1274.25.25.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.cpWWpRSVdvI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.aWM&fp=664143ad430a12dd&biw=1200&bih=796

Comment: What is the purpose of scanf in your code? What is the purpose of getchar in your code? I suggest eliminating one of them. Have a look at the answer I've voted up and decide which one. Should you decide to work with scanf, you need to do a lot more work than you have here... scanf is really unsuitable for this.

@jpw A character literal is an int value, and getchar returns an int value, but I wouldn't suggest that a char is an int. `int x;` Would you suggest that x can store sizeof (int) values of type int?

Comment: @modifiable bad phrasing on my part I guess, you're right that int and char are two different types of course.

Answer (score 2):

Your program should have a "main" function which does the following things:

1. In a loop, call the [`getchar()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) to read a character from the standard input stream (stdin) and store its returned value into a `int` variable named "c" (for example).
2. If the value of "c" is equal to EOF then exit from the loop (e.g. using "break") or from main entirely (using "return", or "exit").
3. If the value of "c" is an upper-case letter (see the [`isupper()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isupper)) then convert it to lower case (see [`tolower()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower)).
4. Print the value of "c" to the standard output stream (stdout) using [`putchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar).

Comment: thank you! I did not even know that library existed until now.